# Relationship between $m(E\backslash F) < \epsilon$ and $m(E)-m(F) < \epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

This may be a fairly easy question but I just want to make sure there are no strange counterexamples.

Suppose $E$ and $F$ are measurable sets such that $F \subset E$.

Now suppose $m(E \setminus F) < \epsilon$ Does this  imply that $m(E)-m(F) < \epsilon$ ?

Comment: Yes, because $m(E - F) = m(E) - m(F)$

Comment: As long as the measure of E is finite, this holds. Since $m(E/F)<\epsilon$, it appears $E$ must be bounded!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $F\subset E$ implies $m(F)+m(E\backslash F)=m(E)$...